# VS Code suddenly stopped closing parenthesis, brackets and curly brackets

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

VS Code suddenly stopped closing parenthesis, brackets and curly brackets.  This started 2 days ago.  I have deleted the extensions I added during these 2 days but no use.

This happens only in JavaScript files, btw.

what could cause this issue with VS Code? Has anyone else run into it before?

Comment: First, try restarting and check if it is working, if that doesn't work uninstall it completely and reinstall.

Comment: turns out it was github copilot causing this issue for javascript files.. had to remove it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Github copilot was causing this issue.  In case someone faces the same issue, disable GitHub Copilot, reload VS Code, and it should work.

if you do not want to disable co-pilot, you can add the following to your vscode settings.json:

```json
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.autoClosingBrackets": "languageDefined"
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue to that. Remove or disable GitHub Copilot from VS Code and then restart VS Code.
It worked for me; I hope it works for you.  If not, please do let me know.